# Update window innerheight when resizing window

Tags: javascript, window, height, window-resize

This far i have succeded to make an Id to have same innerHeight as the window.
However when i resize the window the height stays the same.

Could anyone help me make the Id be the same innerHeight as the window whenever it is resized ?
Here is the code

```
function height()
{
var h = window.innerHeight;

document.getElementById("id").style.height = h+'px'; 
}

height();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this approach might play nicer with existing event handlers:

```
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
  document.getElementById("id").style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I have tried but it seems not to work. Only my code works. See here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/snc06gws/)

Comment: I think what you're seeing there is that your code is firing straight away, whereas ours are waiting for the window.resize() event. However, all three divs cannot take up 100% of the space, so since yours is first, it's the one we see. http://jsfiddle.net/m6nto9ns/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById("id").style.height = h+'px'; 
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks. I have tried but it seems not to work. Only my code works. See here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/snc06gws/)